# How to make my 1D EM algorithm written in Julia faster?

Tags: performance, julia

I wrote this code that's supposed to implement a 1-dimensional (!) [EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) with k-means initialization:

```
begin
    import Pkg
    Pkg.activate(temp=true)
    Pkg.add(["StaticArrays"; "Plots"; "BenchmarkTools"])
end

using Printf
using LinearAlgebra: norm
using Statistics: quantile
using StaticArrays

"Density of standard normal distribution"
@inline ϕ(x) = exp(-x^2 / 2) / sqrt(2π)

"""
Log likelihood to be optimized:

    ∑ₜlog(∑ᵢpᵢ * ϕ((xₜ - μᵢ) / σᵢ))
"""
@inline log_likelihood(x, p, μ, σ) = sum(log.((p ./ σ)' * ϕ.((x' .- μ) ./ σ)))

# Termination criteria
@inline metric_l1(θ₀::AbstractVector, θ₁::AbstractVector) = maximum(abs.(θ₀ - θ₁))
@inline metric_l2(θ₀::AbstractVector, θ₁::AbstractVector) = norm(θ₀ - θ₁)

"""
All parameters are stored into a single vector θ,
but sometimes individual parameters (p, μ, σ) need to be accessed.
`get_pμσ` implements this access.
"""
@inline function get_pμσ(θ::AbstractVector, k::Integer)
    p = @view θ[1:k]
    μ = @view θ[k + 1:2k]
    σ = @view θ[2k + 1:end]
    
    p, μ, σ
end

@inline function get_pμσ(θ::MVector{_3k}) where _3k
    k = Int(_3k / 3)
    p = @view θ[1:k]
    μ = @view θ[k + 1:2k]
    σ = @view θ[2k + 1:end]
    
    p, μ, σ
end

"""
Storage for all data needed for EM algorithm.

`k` - integer that specifies the number of components
 in the mixture;
`_3k` - `3 * k`, needed for `StaticArrays`
"""
mutable struct EMData{k, T <: Real, _3k}
    # Parameters to be estimated
    θ::MVector{_3k, T}
    θ_old::MVector{_3k, T}
    θ_tmp::MVector{_3k, T}
    
    # Probabilities for each component
    probs::MVector{k, T}
    probs_tmp::MVector{k, T}
    distances::MVector{k, T}

    # Vector to store temporary `p ./ σ`
    pσ::MVector{k, T}
    
    function EMData(x::AbstractVector{T}, k::UInt) where T <: Real
        @assert k > 1
        k = Int(k)
        
        # Initialize parameters
        θ = MVector([
            # pᵢ = 1/k
            ones(k) ./ k;
            # μᵢ = quantile(i)
            quantile(x, range(zero(T), one(T), length=k));
            # σᵢ = 1
            ones(k)
        ]...)
        θ_old = @MVector zeros(T, 3k)
        θ_tmp = MVector{3k, T}(undef)
        
        probs = MVector{k, T}(undef)
        probs_tmp = MVector{k, T}(undef)
        distances = MVector{k, T}(undef)
        
        new{k, T, 3k}(
            θ, θ_old, θ_tmp,
            probs, probs_tmp, distances,
            MVector{k, T}(undef)
        )
    end
end

"""
Actual EM algorithm.

Fit the model to data in `x`.
"""
function em!(
        data::EMData{k, T}, x::AbstractVector{T};
        tol::T=3e-4, eps::T=1e-6, metric=metric_l2
    ) where {k, T <: Real}
    # All of these are "pointers" into `θ`
    p, μ, σ = get_pμσ(data.θ)
    p_tmp, μ_tmp, σ_tmp = get_pμσ(data.θ_tmp)

    i = 0
    while i == 0 || metric(data.θ, data.θ_old) > tol
        data.probs .= μ_tmp .= σ_tmp .= zero(T)
        
        if i < 4
            # Initialization steps using k-means
            @inbounds for x_ ∈ x
                # Get index of the centroid closest
                # to the current data point `x_`
                idx = argmin(abs.(μ .- x_))
                
                # Temporary computations for
                # new centroids and standard deviations
                # for each cluster
                μ_tmp[idx] += x_
                σ_tmp[idx] += (x_ - μ[idx])^2

                # Temporary computations for probabilities
                # for a data point to be part of this cluster.
                # These aren't really probabilities,
                # but number of items in `x` that
                # are closest to the centroid number `idx`.
                data.probs[idx] += 1
            end
        else
            # EM step
            data.pσ .= p ./ σ
            for x_ ∈ x
                # These are basically the heights of each Gaussian at `x_`
                data.distances .= data.pσ .* ϕ.((x_ .- μ) ./ σ)
                # Probabilities that `x_` belongs to each component
                data.probs_tmp .= data.distances ./ sum(data.distances)

                # ``
                μ_tmp .+= x_ .* data.probs_tmp
                σ_tmp .+= (x_ .- μ).^2 .* data.probs_tmp
                data.probs .+= data.probs_tmp
            end
        end
        
        data.θ_old .= data.θ
        
        # We'll divide by `data.probs` later,
        # so make sure there are no zeros
        data.probs .+= eps

        # Probabilities to choose each mixture component
        p .= data.probs ./ sum(data.probs)

        # Update centers and standard deviations of mixture components
        μ .= μ_tmp ./ data.probs
        σ .= sqrt.(σ_tmp ./ data.probs) .+ eps
        
        i += 1
    end
    
    i, μ, σ, p
end

x = [
0.000177951775538746, 0.00392297222083862, 0.00573375518171434, -0.00215401267990863, 0.000538068347660303,
-0.00143420605437389, 0.000896137706713716, 0.000896941489857404, 0.00107739281386029, 0.0,
-0.00179501035452376, -0.00429492428288084, -0.00658541135833433, 0.00355429554914226, -0.00160099651736935,
-0.000888336204816467, 0.00195538236688178, 0.00445832214171123, 0.00483741873177002, -0.000718132885440779,
0.00377596420953514, 0.00342867790551233, -0.00306831754125248, 0.00397255849263816, 0.0,
-0.000361794504669915, -0.00144587048503415, -0.000361141210136725, -0.00054146738981984, 0.000180456555574247,
-0.00252343320638076, 0.00270392233240091, 0.00488556115164594, 0.00764752452585767, 0.00476365869676501,
0.00147031822114039, 0.00276268708730977, -0.00129020384684025, 0.00535600135308521, 0.000926354860130661,
0.00371402469637161, -0.00278681090717928, -0.00092721378919225, 0.000370782355008043, 0.000556431434184263,
-0.00055643143418421, 0.000556431434184263, 0.00204290162980033, 0.000929973097806059, 0.00447594928538436,
0.00149644622014601, -0.00149644622014607, -0.0102278901832563, 0.0232089773663753, 0.00474519254248678,
-0.000190240655001527, -0.00190041866394127, 0.00152004589404511, 0.000951203343859139, -0.00057083057396285,
-0.000190204470378469, 0.00782820226743366, 0.0042258994890649, 0.00231258534362122, 0.00347893663596757,
-0.000967585948735971, -0.00386100865745943, 0.00173560934514597, 0.00115874868121845, 0.0,
-0.00597246742094086, 0.0113977859017562, -0.00116504867546977, -0.00329361917425058, 0.000967585948736038,
-0.0130796248184689, -0.0146071078637767, 0.00320664237799695, -0.00395965446177131, -0.0018800531952435,
0.00527308189815804, -0.0013208795202859, 0.00605260028192317, 0.000379506645921242, -0.0039776546430593,
-0.00283152619573845, -0.000753721535588146, 0.00150801159586541, -0.00451722958981981, -0.0221013731937308,
0.000183705337156579, -0.000734618949474405, -0.00293309101204326, -0.00073193049928161, -0.00310474178720573,
-0.0032769008023148, 0.0, 0.00711357308880216, -0.00128052702030923, -0.00182648452603419,
0.0, -0.00145878946365998, 0.000729128723516206, -0.00273149582560972, 0.000181867782623716,
0.000727802069971813, -0.00109150456534317, 0.0146522767868704, -0.000184484826646273, 0.000738143602439221,
-0.00772346612385879, -0.000915499468868335, 0.00587373201209392, 0.00943315974911239, -0.000928763882124529,
0.00839009303177396, -0.00392413845613426, 0.00504815506005073, -0.00262074279539635, -0.00298674853354866,
-0.00372093452569019, 0.00278940208757859, 0.00916665290654104, -0.00580906721169516, -0.00149365225678325,
-0.0129751588631334, -0.00587588910566919, 0.00293362879994538, 0.00829727264081383, -0.00535501233509002,
-0.00183992692200718, 0.00997606647844415, 0.031497181728131, 0.00364718707389437, 0.0,
0.00520583456600374, -0.00212416802859568, 0.00483419678746064, -0.00116234030908892, 0.00855537009118863,
0.00195465269427087, -0.0141818792638312, -0.00269697716932484, 0.0190333964890183, 0.00058840837237535,
-0.020006494229477, 0.00675352301577992, -0.0023206353481625, 0.0030953787531742, 0.000581451707437155,
0.00174638639514873, 0.000388500393386961, 0.00917348094033744, 0.0045200037650227, 0.0017742735063647,
-0.00157728739324861, 0.000591191267588397, 0.00652627650127567, -0.000793336019395874, -0.00474684435621956,
0.00554018037561535, -0.0235304974101942, -0.00232288141613964, -0.00135252653214332, -0.00250699196003446,
-0.00652718769663178, -0.00439141517174207, -0.00247360034793817, 0.000950660780790026, -0.0077688690125669,
0.00151114497967001, 0.00682855460685999, 0.00190512536189465, 0.000763067568502649, -0.00266819293039737,
0.00362284694084784, 0.0124941558021624, -0.00674701354659438, -0.000192104505441552, 0.0172434767494189,
0.00136892560734174, 0.00352872352045298, -0.00117762525876351, 0.00157047539149226, -0.00274671548005741,
-0.0109120334509827, 0.00388350002639761, 0.0, -0.000972289818939222, -0.000388651384604448,
-0.00619796677113697, 0.00115919642037643, -0.00328090615641925, 0.00192864090640569, 0.00425614881223867,
0.000193892390331064, -0.00830361051855981, -0.0105213787415328, 0.00324025824339414, -0.00609061646775083,
0.00323102058144654, 0.000571265368292208, -0.00171281800367483, 0.00266565275894659, 0.013629158084423,
-0.00135200406881384, 0.0025123213523506, -0.00173997143946368, 0.00348297565725149, -0.00271002875886502,
0.00077354480747565, 0.0, 0.00893904125683704, 0.00508807359916059, -0.000392310715114109,
-0.0234529598215287, 0.00499328865399085, 0.0025060254079053, 0.0096975158728236, -0.00563600753364361,
0.000775494416530351, -0.00734302816361565, 0.00212007403298724, 0.000192957067651188, -0.00442861992701387,
]

data = EMData(x, UInt(5))
i, μ, σ, p = em!(data, x)

@show log_likelihood(x, p, μ, σ)
```

Output:

```
log_likelihood(x, p, μ, σ) = 865.892804300474
```

Side note: the log-likelihood gets to 864 by iteration 15 and then spends 300+ iterations climbing to 865.89:

```
(i, ll) = (0, 846.5355881703103)
(i, ll) = (1, 850.7556512372836)
(i, ll) = (2, 852.6190804601607)
(i, ll) = (3, 852.9874081416267)
(i, ll) = (4, 860.0518727031077)
(i, ll) = (5, 862.0286646438534)
(i, ll) = (6, 862.8927967930032)
(i, ll) = (7, 863.3682717865164)
(i, ll) = (8, 863.6668603362682)
(i, ll) = (9, 863.8705036652785)
(i, ll) = (10, 864.0174642505768)
(i, ll) = (11, 864.1280388914373)
(i, ll) = (12, 864.2140020498402)
(i, ll) = (13, 864.2826465763644)
(i, ll) = (14, 864.338720334462)
(i, ll) = (15, 864.3854377968222)
...
(i, ll) = (320, 865.8782037597581)
(i, ll) = (321, 865.8827824031083)
(i, ll) = (322, 865.8863255090024)
(i, ll) = (323, 865.8890568445889)
(i, ll) = (324, 865.8911657112117)
(i, ll) = (325, 865.892804300474)
```

I read SQUAREM has better convergence, but it kept putting negative values for the probabilities `p` and standard deviations `σ`...

To plot the results (this code is OK):

```
using Plots

function plot_kde(x::AbstractVector, p::AbstractVector, μ::AbstractVector, σ::AbstractVector; N=200, fname="kde.png")
    log_lik = log_likelihood(x, p, μ, σ)
    X = range(-.03, .03, length=N)
    kde = zeros(size(X))

    plt = histogram(
        x, normalize=:pdf,
        title=@sprintf("Log-likelihood: %.4f", log_lik), label="Histogram",
        linewidth=0, alpha=.5
    )

    for (p, μ, σ) ∈ zip(p, μ, σ)
        pdf = (p / σ) .* ϕ.((X .- μ) ./ σ)
        kde .+= pdf
        plot!(plt, X, pdf, label=@sprintf("p=%.2f μ=%+.3f σ=%.3f", p, μ, σ))
    end
    
    plot!(plt, X, kde, label="KDE", linewidth=2)
    savefig(plt, fname)
end

plot_kde(x, p, μ, σ)
```

---

First things first, I think this code is correct because I followed the papers on EM, derived the formulas and the results look fine (generated by `plot_kde` above):

[image]

It also increases the log-likelihood on each step, *like* EM, so it should indeed *be* the correct EM, but it's rather slow.

Benchmarking this with `BenchmarkTools.jl`:

```
let 
    data = EMData(x, UInt(30))
    @benchmark em!(data, x)
end
```

...gives these results:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  112.64 KiB
  allocs estimate:  901
  --------------
  minimum time:     15.459 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      16.128 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        16.197 ms (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     18.063 ms (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          309
  evals/sample:     1
```

If I use the k-means algorithm instead of EM, the timings are in the order of microseconds, and the resulting log-likelihood isn't that much worse than what EM gives. I need to run this algorithm a million times (and with about 30 mixture components!) on similar vectors of length ~300, so I would like to squeeze as much performance out of this as possible.

I'm pretty new to Julia, and I often discover new ways to speed up Julia code (sometimes drastically, like [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/sum-log-p-c-is-2-to-4-times-slower-than-in-numpy/53960)), so I could easily be missing optimizations here. How can this code be improved and sped up?

Comment: I've tried some refactoring for fun: https://gist.github.com/phipsgabler/4d91bcee6d3d56021ee485b8dd00a5fc. But I can't really comment on whether this is working or an improvement, so I won't make it an answer.

Comment: @phipsgabler, thanks, this code indeed looks cleaner than mine. This also reminded me about the existence of `clamp` - I'm always forgetting about it

Comment: Have you considered using `DifferentialEquations` for this? It should be much faster since it will do much fancier sampling.

Comment: @OscarSmith, how would it help, though? I'm not solving any differential equations here and not sampling anything - I'm trying to fit a Gaussian mixture model to my data. Can DifferentialEquations estimate GMMs?

Comment: Nevermind, I saw the title and didn't look at the code.